# update different db collection inside another db collection foreach method

Tags: mongodb

```
use AppID
db.Coll1.find().forEach( function(coll1Row){
    use NewStore
    db.Col2.insert(coll1Row.val);
});
```

trying to change db inside a forEach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
   use AppID
    newdb = db.getSiblingDB("NewStore")
    db.Coll1.find().forEach(function(doc){ newdb.Coll2.insert(doc)})
```